# goldmoney payment gateway implementation in Magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, magento-1.9, payment

I planned to build a ECommerce website in `Magento`. In this, I need `goldmoney payment method` for checkout. I searched about `goldmoney payment` for `Magento`, but I didn't get any valuable result.

Please someone help me to get this done and suggest me other ways to get this done.

Also suggest me how can i create developer account for testing in goldmoney.

`goldmoney` pay button only available. But that will not suitable for `Magento`.

**Note:** I am not much knowledge about `goldmoney` payment method or gateway.

Comment: why you want particularly `goldmoney payment` , you can use paypal or cash on delivery or others, if you need `goldmoney payment` try contacting official team.....

Comment: goldmoney payment is new so only I am willing to use this

Answer (score 0):

If the payment integration doesn't exist, you'll need to create one.
To integrate a new payment method in Magento 1 you'll need to:

- know about the payment API and workflow
- create a (payment) module for Magento

There are plenty of material about creating payment module for magento out there. Here are some of them:

- [Inchoo](https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/)
- [Excellence Magento Blog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/28/magento-create-custom-payment-method/)
- [A quick wizard for creating payment module](http://schogini.biz/magento-payment-module-creator/)